# Calling a synchronized method from a new thread created inside another synchronized method of the same class in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Assuming a class has two methods like the ones below:

```
public synchronized void methodA() {
  // do some stuff

  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      methodB();
    }
  }.start();
}

public synchronized void methodB() {
  // do some stuff
}
```

and we call `methodA()`, will the new thread be blocked by the one that called `methodA()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not: `new Thread().start()` returns immediately, so by the time the new thread actually gets started and `methodB()` is called, it is very likely that the original thread will have already exited `methodA()`.

If however you do:

```
public synchronized void methodA() throws InterruptedException {
  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      methodB();
    }
  }.start();
  Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

your `methodB` will block for approximately 10 seconds, waiting for the original thread to release the lock.